# Innodb: If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index record is set

Tags: locking, sql-insert, innodb

background: mysql-refman-5.7

```
mysql> show create table t1 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `i` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`i`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> select * from t1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

```
session1: --------------- operation 1
start transaction;
insert into t1 values(1);
```

```
session2: --------------- operation 2
insert into t1 values(1);
```

```
session3: --------------- operation 3
start transaction;
insert into t1 values(1);
```

```
session1: --------------- operation 4
rollback;
```

the ref explains the process above as follows:

1. operation 1 acquires an Exclusive lock the row.
2. operation 2,3 both result in duplicate-key error and the both request a shard lock the row.
3. after operation 4, session1 releases its exclusive lock on the row and session2,3 grant the shared lock.

Q1:
After operation 2,3, both two session are waiting the exclusive lock for the row util timeout if operation 4 is not executed. right? But there is no msg of "duplicate-key error" like the list item NO.2 above.
[image]

Q2:
why session2 and session3 request a shared lock for the row when duplicate-key error happends? Should not the both session end as result of exception?

Q3:
Will duplicate-key error be thrown out as error message prompt?

Q4:
Why does not duplicate-key error end the session?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with these:

> Q3: Will duplicate-key error be thrown out as error message prompt?
> Q4: Why does not duplicate-key error end the session?

Without knowing which client is issuing the SQL, I can't discuss "throwing" and "ending" or "message prompts".

Generally speaking, InnoDB was designed with these in mind, in this order:

1. ACID -- Getting the 'right' answer in every case, even if the power is pulled from the server.
2. Speed *for the common case*.

In the Speed case...

- `COMMIT` runs faster than `ROLLBACK`.  This is a deliberate choice based on `COMMIT` being more common.
- Deadlocks are recognized immediately -- even if this means sometimes claiming a deadlock that *could* have been avoided.
- Complex cases are so rare that they probably punt rather than spending any extra effort trying to figure it out.

I think (without knowing for sure) that your 3-connection conflict falls in this last case.

Comment: The client is ITerm terminator.

Comment: Q2: when session1 rollback,and session 2 grants the X lock to insert the row, at this point, session 3 is about to insert the same row and duplicated error happend, right? But seesion 2 has done it, and duplicated error is only about session 3 and has nothing to do with session 2 right?

Comment: This may come under the category I called "complex".